# Mysql Search Postcodes

Tags: php, mysql, search, postal-code

I want to create a mysql search query, that will search for postcodes here is what i have done so far

```
SELECT * FROM orders where ( InvoicePostcode LIKE 'b%' OR InvoicePostcode LIKE 'ws%') order by InvoiceNumber asc
```

I want to display only postcode starting with b or ws but the problem is some post contain bb or BS at the start of the postcode for example

> BS24 8EE
>
> BB9 8SY

the only ones that should be showing that start with b like this one B65 0NQ im not sure how to check postcode by only looking at the letter at the start before the numbers in the postcode

Comment: search for other similar questions in stackoverflow. Some are suggesting regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use regexp to exclude certain pattern:

In the below I exclude InvoicePostcode containing B followed by a letter

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE (InvoicePostcode LIKE 'b%' AND NOT InvoicePostcode RLIKE '^(B[A-Z])')
    OR (InvoicePostcode LIKE 'ws%' AND NOT InvoicePostcode RLIKE '^(WS[A-Z])')
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) to solve this issue.

What you need to know is the pattern you are searching for, to give you an example if you are searching for all postcodes starting with B only then you know that these postcodes will

1. Must have first character as B. There are examples in link to select first character (^) and 1 instance({1} equal to 'B' or 'b'.
2. Second character can be any number

Similarly you can do for all other patterns as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP clause for the same.

E.g.:
select * from orders where (InvoicePostcode REGEXP '^B[^BS].*' OR InvoicePostcode REGEXP '^WS.*')

'^B[^BS].*' in this it will ignore words start with BB OR BS.

Hope it'll help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE (InvoicePostcode LIKE 'b%' AND NOT InvoicePostcode RLIKE '^(B[A-Z])')
    OR (InvoicePostcode LIKE 'ws%' AND NOT InvoicePostcode RLIKE '^(WS[A-Z])')
ORDER BY InvoiceNumber ASC
```

pls refer : https://www.guru99.com/regular-expressions.html

RLIKE operator performs a pattern match of a string expression against a pattern. The pattern is supplied as an argument. The following MySQL statement will find the author’s name beginning with ‘B’. The ‘^’ have been used to match the beginning of the name.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE InvoicePostcode RLIKE '^B';
```

[A-Z]
Matches any uppercase letter​

[a-z]
Matches any lowercase letter​

'^(B[A-Z])'means it will work as first letter B and whether next is A to Z are not.